# Postcss-loader flex-start warnings

Tags: css, angular, spartacus-storefront, postcss-loader

I'm using SAP Spartacus/Composable Storefront 6.5 and receiving some postcss-loader warnings when start the project, about the end/flex-end use inside the lib.

```bash
Build at: 2023-10-28T17:39:59.198Z - Hash: 6048ae368e6ccd8f - Time: 39068ms

./src/styles/main.scss - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(11328:3) autoprefixer: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead

./src/styles/main.scss - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(13030:3) autoprefixer: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead

./src/styles/main.scss - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(15228:3) autoprefixer: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead

./src/app/footer/footer-nav/footer-nav.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(8:3) autoprefixer: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead
```

I know this is a just warning and maybe not affect anything on the build, but have how I can hide this warnings if I cant fix?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've got somewhere in your CSS `justify-content` or `align-content` value set to `end` instead of `flex-end`.

Comment: I know, but this is inside the Spartacus Storefront lib, and not on my own code.